# append img after html text

Tags: javascript, jquery, insertafter

Im trying to append an img right after a piece of text. Im using 'embedly' to load news items, so I have to perform on window load. Its really simple: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2VBSX/13/)

I cant figure out why its not working. I have tried many combinations and events(after,Insert etc) nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.after` method.

```
$('.embed').find('.description').after('<img src="http://latitudes.nu/wp-content/themes/theme-framework/framework/media/images/comment_icon.gif" style="width:14px; height:14px; border:none;" />');
```

***[A fix to your demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/2VBSX/19/)***

*But, use `setTimeout` is not a good idea, you should set the callback option as the plugin provide.*

Comment: Thank you:) To tell you the truth, I asked the wrong question...I already know how to append. The main thing about my question was "How to append right after the .description text" In your example the img is "below" the text...(I would really appreciate it if you could help me out)

Comment: Hmmm, thats really weird, I was doing append all the time and it never worked. Anyway, it works now, thanks for sticking around:)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#element").append("<img src=\"image\">");
```

Comment: do you know how to get it after the html text?